# JAVA ldap error NO_OBJECT

Tags: java, ldap

I'm in trouble with this error when I change a password or update user's info.
I've tried so many codes that are similar each others, but I still got the error.
The problem can be a bad CN definition, but should be correct in my case and I'm really sad about this because I cannot face the problem.

- Connection to the server via LDAP: *OK*.
- SSL and cacerts: *OK*.
- Add user via code: *OK*.
- Fetching all users info: *OK*.
- Update user's info: **BAD**.

Here is a simple code where I try, without success, to update the user's info (description).
The user "batman" obviously, exists in AD.

```
public class ADConnection {

DirContext ctx = null;
String baseName = ",OU=SoftwareV3,OU=SOFTWARE,DC=SOFTWAREDEV,DC=LOCAL";
String serverIP = "192.168.10.45";
boolean ssl = true;

public ADConnection() {
    try {
        Hashtable ldapEnv = new Hashtable(); 
        ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,             "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"); 
        if(ssl==true)
        {
            ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://192.168.10.45:636/dc=softwaredev,dc=local");
            ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        }
        else
        {
            ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.10.45:389/dc=softwaredev,dc=local");
        }
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple"); 
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, new String("softwaredev" + "\\" +     "superadmin"));
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "passw0rd");  
        ctx = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println(" bind error: " + e); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        System.exit(-1); 
    } 
}

public void updateDescription(String username) {
    try {
      System.out.println("updating...\n");
      ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
      mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,
        new BasicAttribute("description", "batman_description"));
      ctx.modifyAttributes("CN=" + username + baseName, mods);
      System.out.println("update successful!!!");
     }
      catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" update error: " + e);
        System.exit(-1);
      }
  }

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    ADConnection adc = new ADConnection(); 
    adc.updateDescription("batman");
    } 
    }
```

**ERROR:**
*update error: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:*

The crash is on the 6th line of code in the function updateDescription.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This could be because of your Fully Qualified Domain Name of the user is incorrect. Using any LDAP browser like JXplorer please  double check the FQDN of the user and ensure that this is the one that you are using in your code

Comment: Ok, I've tried with uPn. The error turns into "BAD_NAME".
But if I type uncorrectly the current baseName, the error is still NO_OBJECT. Isn't really strange?

Comment: The UPN is a different attribute, you need to find the `CN` attribtue value of the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your code, and the error message, AD is saying that the DN `CN=batman,OU=SoftwareV3,OU=SOFTWARE,DC=SOFTWAREDEV,DC=LOCAL` does not exist. This message pertains to the *entire* DN tree.

This means that either of these objects does not exist:

- DC=LOCAL
- DC=SOFTWAREDEV,DC=LOCAL
- OU=SOFTWARE,DC=SOFTWAREDEV,DC=LOCAL
- OU=SoftwareV3,OU=SOFTWARE,DC=SOFTWAREDEV,DC=LOCAL
- CN=batman,OU=SoftwareV3,OU=SOFTWARE,DC=SOFTWAREDEV,DC=LOCAL

You should check the entire DN for correctness, using an LDAP browser, as the error message does not specify *which* object does not exist.

Comment: Thanks to wireshark, I got the error and the last of the list was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code the line would look like this:

```
ctx.modifyAttributes("CN=batman,OU=SoftwareV3,OU=SOFTWARE,DC=SOFTWAREDEV,DC=LOCAL", mods);
```

Try it like this, it works for me:

```
ctx.modifyAttributes("CN=batman,OU=SoftwareV3,OU=SOFTWARE", mods);
```

I followed the example that can be seen in this link:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.naming.directory/DirContextmodifyAttributesStringnameintmodopAttributesattrs.htm